# postgresql request over several schema

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have a database, with every users having a schema.

Is there a way to query a table in every schema?

Something like: **`select id, name from *.simulation`** doesn't work...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: more details: the result must be something like "select id, name from user1.simulation union select id, name from user2.simulation union ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to write a function - either a server side function or a client side function in whatever language you're using - that executes the query once for each schema.

You could also create a VIEW that does UNION ALL between all the schemas, but that's going to be a lot of work to maintain if your schemas are dynamically added and removed.

Comment: Thank you, I try to write a stored procedure, with some difficulties... (Another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546488/postgresql-stored-procedure-with-querie-on-several-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use **SET search_path TO ...** to point to all schema's. If you don't know all the names of the schemas, wrap it in a function that first selects all schemas and then set the entire search_path.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set.html

Comment: That will still only get you the table from the first schema listed that has one named that, not all of them at once.