# postgresql stored procedure with query on several schema

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, schema

After some answer on a previous question ([request over several schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545990/postgresql-request-over-several-schema)), I try to write a stored procedure to select tables for several schemas (Each user have a schema).

```
create or replace public.select_simulations() returns setof simulation as $$
declare 
    users pg_user%ROWTYPE;
    simu simulation%ROWTYPE;
begin
    for users in select usename from pg_user where usename <> 'postgres' loop
        for simu in select id, name from (users.usename).simulation loop            
            return next simu;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end; 
$$
```

but it doesn't accept the `(users.usename).simulation`, and without the parenthesis it produced an error (seems to search a sub field, not a schema)...

So what is the correct syntax to tell that `users.usename` is a schema name ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I use PostgreSQL 8.1, maybe its matter...

Comment: Version 8.1 will be out of service this year, you'd better upgrade to a newer version. PostgreSQL has become much better since november 2005 as well, just a waist of time to make something for this old and outdated version. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I upgrade to 8.4.

Comment: Release policy has been moved to official site: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the for-in-execute control structure:

```
FOR record_or_row IN EXECUTE text_expression LOOP 
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Something like:

```
...

for users in select usename from pg_user where usename <> 'postgres' loop
    for simu in execute 'select id, name from '||quote_ident(users.usename)||'.simulation' loop
        return next simu;
    end loop;
end loop;
...
```